# Saving an Outlook Item VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, outlook, save

I'm having trouble saving the outlook item. (Hmmm, I just realized I'm working with Ms Word - does it matter? Can I still post here?) Anyways, the issue is that, Word is creating the Message and sending it just fine (with attachments, subject and everything), but it is not saving the file in the designated location properly. It is saving as 1 KB and not opening. Below is the code and an image of the error. Thanks much for your help!

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim myString As String
Dim myString2 As String


Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' Doing some texts replacements here.
myString = Label9
myString = Replace(myString, "[Name of Person]", TextBoxNoP.Value)
myString = Replace(myString, "[Name of Establishment]", TextBoxNoE.Value)
myString = Replace(myString, "[Date Received]", TextBoxDR.Value)


myString2 = Label10
myString2 = Replace(myString2, "[Name of Establishment]", TextBoxNoE.Value)
myString2 = Replace(myString2, "[Date Received]", TextBoxDR.Value)

' Done with texts replacements here. Setting up, saving and sending messages.
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

myItem.To = TextBoxTo.Value
myItem.CC = TextBoxCC.Value
myItem.Subject = myString2
myAttachments.Add "\\di-afs.doi-ad.state.nv.us\LifeHealth\Charitable Gift Annuities\Charitable Gift Annuities 2016\Pending Charitable Gift Annunites\" & TextBoxAtt.Value & ".pdf"
myItem.Body = myString
myItem.SaveAs "\\di-afs.doi-ad.state.nv.us\LifeHealth\Charitable Gift Annuities\Charitable Gift Annuities 2016\E-mails sent by Nanci\" & myString2 & ".msg", olMsg
myItem.Send




Unload Me


End Sub
```

[image: link to screenshot of error]

Thanks much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call myItem.Save before calling SaveAs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I needed to remove the ", olMsg" part from the end of the SaveAs line. Thanks anyways!